# How to redefine a color for a specific value in a colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I want to use the colormap `rainbow` in an image using `imshow`. It works perfectly, but I want to redefine the color for the value `0`. Instead of violete, I want to use white.

I want to do this only for the value zero, all other values can stay with the default values in the colormap.

Any idea how to do this **without** having to edit the colormap manually?

Comment: You should [not use the rainbow colour map](https://eagereyes.org/basics/rainbow-color-map).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can also use `set_under` which I think makes more semantic sense than using `set_bad`

```
my_cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
my_cmap.set_under('w')
imshow(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5),
       interpolation='none',
       cmap=my_cmap,
       vmin=.001)
```

You can tweak the colorbar to also show the 'under' (and the symmetric 'over') color using the kwarg `extend`, see [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html) and [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar).

For an answer to a duplicate with more complete examples see [How to create matplotlib colormap that treats one value specially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432654/how-to-create-matplotlib-colormap-that-treats-one-value-specially?noredirect=1#comment39706467_25432654)