# How to create matplotlib colormap that treats one value specially?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I create a matplotlib colormap that maps `0` (and *only* `0`) to white, and any other value `0 < v <= 1` to a smooth gradient such as `rainbow`?

It seems neither `LinearSegmentedColormap` nor `ListedColormap` can do this.

Comment: @tcaswell Indeed a duplicate, but the answer *here* is much better.  `vmin = 0.001` is not good engouh.  I have to always keep in mind what the minimum nonzero value might be in my matrix.

Comment: Are you saying the relevant part of the answer here is the `0 + eps`?  I marked them duplicate in chronological order, @JoeKington has the power to re-order them or appeal to meta if you have a major protest.  (and I agree Joe's answer _is_ a better answer (and up-voted!))

Comment: @tcaswell There's no protest at all, I just mentioned that I thought Joe's answer was more useful because it shows how to use `eps` (I didn't know) and it gives a solution for when `0` is in the middle.

Comment: See the edit to my answer on the other question.  Added a link back to this.

Comment: @tcaswell I didn't actually realize until now that the other answer was written by you.  It's also a very useful, I didn't mean to say it wasn't.  Thanks for adding the link!  My point was that it was indeed useful for people who find your answer to also see the `eps` trick (in case they can't figure it out, like me).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing it.  From your description of your values range, you just want to use `cmap.set_under('white')` and then set the `vmin` to `0 + eps`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
cmap.set_under('white')  # Color for values less than vmin

data = np.random.random((10, 10))
data[3:5, 7:] = 0

# Very small float such that 0.0 != 0 + eps
eps = np.spacing(0.0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', vmin=eps, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im, extend='min')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if 0 was in the middle of your data range, you could mask the values and set the color with `cmap.set_bad` (I'll use black as the color to distinguish from the default for masked portions.):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
cmap.set_bad('black')

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 10))
data[3:5, 7:] = 0

data = np.ma.masked_equal(data, 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean set vmin to 0 + eps?  Can you check my edit please?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! (It wouldn't have worked with `vmin=0`.) Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Marked this question as duplicate, you are revert my close vote and close the duplicates the other way if you want.

Comment: @tcaswell - I'm not worried about it one way or another. They're both good (albeit duplicate) answers. Let's just leave it with this one closed.

Comment: I don't think this is really a duplicate since the question asks to replace the color for one of the levels. I will not reopen this question, but for people indeed seeking to use a different color *inside* the colormap, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613920/use-of-extend-in-a-pcolormesh-plot-with-discrete-colorbar) on how to do it.