# How to generate a new rainbow colormap using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I need to plot an image filled with geophysical values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 using a rainbow colormap.

I tried the existing rainbow colormap from matplotlib but I am not fully satisfied with it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.pcolor(np.random.rand(10,10),cmap='rainbow')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

How do I create a colormap that ranges from black for a value of 0.0 and then gradually shows the following colors: violet, blue, cyan, green, yellow and finally red for a value of 1.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create own colormap using matplotlib and plot color scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap as suggested in [cookbook matplotlib](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.1, 0.5, 0.5),
                 (0.2, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.4, 0.2, 0.2),
                 (0.6, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.8, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
        'green':((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.1, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.2, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.4, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.6, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.8, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
        'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.1, 0.5, 0.5),
                 (0.2, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.4, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (0.6, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.8, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}

my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',cdict,256)
plt.pcolor(np.random.rand(10,10),cmap=my_cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the edit, I didn't had enough reputation to post an image at the time I posted the answer!

Comment: Another option that may work for you is to use a standard colormap with `set_under`, as done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432654/how-to-create-matplotlib-colormap-that-treats-one-value-specially  In your usage the black is continuous with the colormap and with `set_under` it's not.

Comment: yes thanks but I also need the other colors (e.g. yellow, cyan) that are not available in the original rainbow colormap.