# Use of extend in a pcolormesh plot with discrete colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, colormap

I'm trying to create a pcolormesh plot with a discrete colorbar. The output should fulfil these criteria:

1. The first level should be white
2. The data should be cut off at some level
3. Data above the cut off should have a separate colour (namely the last colour of the colormap)

I am almost there but the 'extend' keyword does not behave the way I would expect it to (the colour in the "max-arrow" is the same as for the last level - see example). **How do I set values above 'vmax' to a separate colour (i.e., the last colour of whatever colormap I use)**

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = xr.Dataset(
    coords={'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, 10),
            'lat': np.arange(-85, 90, 10)},
    data_vars={'data': (('lat', 'lon'), np.random.rand(18, 36))})

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
cmap.set_under('w')
# cmap.set_over()  # do something here?
levels = np.arange(0, .7, .1)
ds.data.plot.pcolormesh(
    cmap=cmap,
    vmin=levels[1],
    # vmax=levels[-1],
    extend='max',
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=False)
)
```

[image]

I'm using xarray but the behaviour is the same for plt.pcolormesh:

```
p = plt.pcolormesh(
    np.arange(-180, 180, 10),
    np.arange(-85, 90, 10),
    np.random.rand(18, 36),
    cmap=cmap,
    vmin=levels[1],
    # vmax=levels[-1],
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=False)
)
plt.colorbar(p, extend='max')
```

Comment: Wow, there is something strange happening, I would not expect the the above code to give the shown output, as specifying `vmin` *and* `norm`, one of them should overwrite the other, but apparently specifying both seems to give you the desired plot somehow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, if you set `cmap.set_over("blue")` you would see blue as the color of the values exceeding the maximum value.

[image]

However, if you want to use the last color of the colormap as that color for `set_over` you need to make a colormap, which stops at the second last color. To that end, the following rationale may be used. If we aim at 6 different colors from a colormap plus the color for overshooting values, we take 7 colors from that colormap, replace the first with white color and use the first 6 colors as the colors for the boundary interval. The last colors is then used as the color for overshooting values.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

lon,lat = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-180, 180, 10), np.arange(-85, 90, 10))
data = np.sort(np.random.rand(18, 36),axis=1)

# create 7 boundaries between 0 and 0.6, to have 6 intervals
boundaries = np.arange(0, .7, .1)
# create list of 7(!) colors from colormap
cmap_reds = plt.cm.get_cmap('Reds',len(boundaries))
colors = list(cmap_reds(np.arange(len(boundaries))))
#replace first color with white
colors[0] = "white"
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors[:-1], "")
# set over-color to last color of list 
cmap.set_over(colors[-1])

cm = plt.pcolormesh(lon,lat,data,
    cmap=cmap,
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries, ncolors=len(boundaries)-1, clip=False)
)
plt.colorbar(cm, extend="max")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Neat, thanks! Is the default behavior (i.e., same color for last to levels) expected? I was a bit surprised by that and in what case you would want that.

Comment: The little triangle is not a level. The default choice of a colormap hence needs to be to take the first or last value for the _under or _over color, as it has been given no extra information about what else this should correspond to. Using the set_over or set_under you may specify the color to use instead; so yes this is all expected.